# Berryboot and adding partitions

Tags: berryboot

I've got Berryboot 2.0 on one of my SD cards and I'm using it for fooling around with some alternate OSes. For the Linux based ones I would like to share a HOME file system between them (and even if not shared, I prefer that to facilitate backups and make it easier to replace the OS.) I looked at /etc/fstab and everything was commented out. I figured I better ask before I start messing with that (though at this point a total cockup would only mean a reinstall.)

A second and related question is how to add a swap partition. I can do that on a USB drive if that's recommended. I know swap is not recommended for the Pi but I'd rather burn up a USB drive than waste the rest of my life waiting for something to happen. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I left the first two together since they both involve disk partitioning and /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

## setup in dphys-swapfile

edit the swapfile location and size then save the file
for berryboot the swapfile should be in external USB drive

```
sudo vi /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

## setup and turnon swapfile in Rasbian

```
sudo dphys-swapfile setup
sudo dphys-swapfile swapon
```

## check usage

```
free -h
```